# How do I make a footer visible with CSS for print?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with some data and content. I want to make a print version that will display the content and footer not to worry much about the header.

Instead of writing another page just for printing, I was reading about CSS's feature for "@media print".

First, what browsers support it? Since this is an internal feature, it's OK if only the latest browsers support it.

I was thinking of tagging a few DOM elements with a "printable" class, and basically apply "display:block". Is that doable?

How do I achieve this?

EDIT: This is what I have so far:

```
/* Print Style - SuccinctNate */

@media print {
* {display:block;}
.printable, .printable > * {display:block;}

#footer {display:block;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code seems correct . you can  set `display:block` to the items you want to show on the print and `display:none` on everything else.

```
 @media print {
           * { display:none }
           .item_i_want_to_print { display:block;}
 }
```

or you could just hide the ones you don't want to appear on the print

```
 @media print {

           .item_i_do_not_want_to_print { display: none;}
 }
```

it is compatible with every browser . so use it with confidence

[image: browser compatibility]

see more here : **[media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)**

Comment: Great!, you just saved me hours of racking my brain over this CSS